# How to add edit-layer as Plack-middleware?

Tags: perl, plack

I have an idea to add a edit-layer to website as a [Plack middleware](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plack%3a%3aMiddleware).

Explanation: let's say, we create a website, based on some framework and templates and CSS (requesting it like `/some/page`). Now we could create a middleware so that every request to pages starting with `adm` (like `/adm/some/page`) shows the same page, but adds a layer for content editing. So we could easily look and use the page as visitors do, but with double-click on block-level element we could modify or add content. So middleware should bind certain block-elements with certain events (double-click) and set handlers too (with some Javascript library).

For now it is just an idea and i have not seen such approach in any CMS. I am looking for hints and ideas and examples, how to start and implement such system. I hope, there is already done something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it, but I don't think you want to do this. My understanding is that  Plack::Middleware's are supposed to be generic, and implementing a CMS as a plack middleware limits its re-usability, and its out of place, there is no inherent connection between a middleware and a CMS.

See these as examples `Plack::Middleware::OAuth`, `Plack::Middleware::Debug`, `Plack::Middleware::iPhone`, `Plack::Middleware::Image::Scale`, `Plack::Middleware::HTMLMinify`

It would be trivial to add a middleware filter  to insert a form in your html based on `/adm/` or `/admin/` or whatever ... and mapping the url to the dispatch would highly depend on the underlying CMS model/view/controller framework, which is why frameworks such as `Catalyst`, `Mojolicious` and other already provide this feature

See http://advent.plackperl.org/2009/12/day-23-write-your-own-middleware.html
Basically, I think this is a job for a view/controller of your application, a plugin, not a wrapper for your application (middleware)

I know my explanation is lacking but hopefully you catch my drift